SOLVED Raspberry Pi 3B+ No Audio
I recently picked up a Raspberry Pi 3B+ to try to run Steam Link. Steam Link wasn't streaming any sound, and after some troubleshooting I got the sound to work on on a secondary device (steamlink on my phone), but it seems the pi itself still has some audio issues. I get a loud whine as soon as the tip of my headphones cord hits the headphones jack, but I can't tell if this is actually sound, plus I need the sound over HDMI. I tried HDMI over two different devices and the results have been the exact same. I'll list all the info I can here and what I've tried, but I'm not sure what I can do next.
TV: Sansui S55VAUG
OS: Raspberry Pi 64-bit Lite, Debian Bookworm 12
/boot/firmware/config.txt includes
dtparams=audio=on
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d

alsamixer
Card: vc4-hdmi
This sound device does not have any controls

amixer cset numid=3 x
amixer: Control default element write error: Operation not permitted

aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones], device 0: bcm2835 Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones]
    Subdevices: 8/8
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
    Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
    Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
    Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
    Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
    Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
    Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 1: vc4hdmi [vc4-hdmi], device 0: MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0 [MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

speaker-test
speaker-test 1.2.8

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Sample format not available for playback: Invalid argument
Setting of hwparams failed: Invalid argument

UPDATE: SOLVED
After lots of messing around I found this forum post with basically the same problem https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=330349
When I confirmed I could get audio playing with aplay -D sysdefault:CARD=vc4hdmi and aplay -D hdmi:CARD=vd4hdmi,DEV=0, which lead me to this post about config.txt https://stackoverflow.com/a/79080758
I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but since I have a Sansui TV, I also added hdmi_mode=4 following this thread https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=11401
Everything works great after changing my ./asoundrc to make sure card 0 (rather than 1, which hdmi had been before the above changes to config.txt).
It's also worth noting that the above was done while testing on a monitor, and switching back to my tv still showed the tests working but no noise. This was solved by going to alsamixer and hitting m to unmute.

the question section is not the place for the answer ... please remove the answer from the question section and post it in the answer section below ... also remove the SOLVED from the title
